# Does GCE upgrade the container cluster master version of kubernetes automatically?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

According to the following document: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/upgrade 
Google is managing the container cluster master - which they are rolling out new version of kubernetes. I've noticed that the current version on our system is 1.6.10-gke.1 - do you know is i should upgrade myself?

Answer (score 0):

The master is automatically upgraded as described at [the bottom of that page](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/upgrade#opt-in_early_master_upgrades). It isn't upgraded immediately, so that there is time for tests and staged rollouts.